# System config js Angular 2 problems with installing modules. Explanation

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, systemjs

I have recently started to develop with Angular 2. There are a lot of tutorial out there. But one thing I cannot still understand is `systemjs.config.js`.

I understand why is it used, and what is the main purpose of it. But how to use it to add other dependencies is not clear enough.

I am using default package from the Starter repository. 
But as I've mentioned I have troubles with adding new modules.

I have tried several times to include different modules, but after several retries I gave up.

I tried to find a good tutorial or documentation that explains how to deal with this tool in the context of Angular 2, but no results.

For now I cannot install Material Design Lite module.

Here is my `systemjs.config.js` file

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({

        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            '@angular-mdl/core': 'vendor/@angular-mdl/core',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'hammerjs': 'npm:hammerjs/hammer.js',
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular2-mdl': 'vendor/angular2-mdl',
            'primeng': 'npm:primeng'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular2-mdl': {main: 'bundle/angular2-mdl.js'},
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            primeng: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }

    });
})(this);
```

My `index.html`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/material-design-lite/material.min.css">
<script src="/node_modules/material-design-lite/material.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css">    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

But I am still getting the following error.

> Template parse errors: 'mdl-icon' is not a known element: 1. If
>   'mdl-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of
>   this module. 2. If 'mdl-icon'

Please explain how to work with this file. Or at least how to include Material Design Lite module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'vendor' is a general term to describe the place providing your packages, so it could be some form of CDN, or in your case the npm.

The first thing to do would be to replace `vendor/` with `npm:`, that way it will be looking in your project's `node_modules` folder as opposed to a folder called vendor which most probably doesn't exist

Comment: Hey, somewhere in your error it should be giving you the path it's trying to use to find your package. I've had a look at angular2-mdl in node_modules; try changing the path of your 'angular2-mdl' map to equal 'npm:angular2-mdl/bundle/angular2-mdl.js'

Answer (score 0):

Still doesn't know how all that stuff work. But to get it working do the following.

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({

        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',

            'angular2-mdl': 'npm:angular2-mdl/',

        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            'angular2-mdl': {main: 'bundle/angular2-mdl.js'},

        }

    });
})(this);
```

And don't forget to import `MdlModule` in your `app.module.js`

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, MdlModule, HttpModule, MaterialModule, RoutingModule],
```